# Crawl extracted links in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to build a broad continuous crawler and I'm able to extract links but I'm unable to crawl them and extract those links. The end goal of this project is to crawl .au domains and add their root URL to a database.

```
class Crawler (scrapy.Spider):
    name = "crawler"
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='.com'), callback='parse_item')) 
    #This will be changed to allow .au before deployment to only crawl .au sites.

    start_urls = [
        "http://quotes.toscrape.com/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath("//a/@href")
        for u in urls:
            l = ItemLoader(item=Link(), response=response)
            l.add_xpath('url', './/a/@href')
            return l.load_item()
```

Another issue I'm having is that for internal links it's adding a relative url path instead of an absolute one. I have tried to fix it with this section.

```
urls = response.xpath("//a/@href")
        for u in urls:
```

items.py file:

```
class Link(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out and I'm posting the basic code below to help anyone that has the same question in future.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

#Create a list of sites not to crawl. 
#Best to read this from a file containing top 100 sites for example.
denylist = [
    'google.com',
    'yahoo.com',
    'youtube.com'
]

class Crawler (CrawlSpider): #For broad crawl you need to use "CrawlSpider"
    name = "crawler"
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.com', ), 
    deny=(denylist)), follow=True, callback='parse_item'),)

    start_urls = [
        "http://quotes.toscrape.com",
    ]


    def parse_item(self, response):
        # self.logger.info('LOGGER %s', response.url)  
        # use above to log and see info in the terminal

        yield {
            'link': response.url
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ItemLoaders` are useful for creating item objects that need `Processors`.
From your code, I don't see the need to use these. You can simply `yield` a `Request` object.

You can get rid of `Link` class (side note: `pass` is used as a place holder when there is nothing else in the block. So `pass` in your code doesn't make sense)

```
 def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath("//a/@href")
        for u in urls:
           yield scrapy.Request(u, callback=self.your_callback_method)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately the solution doesn't work.
I'm using ItemLoader so I can process the data through a function later, to get whois information and add them to a database. I'm guessing that's what  it's for? Otherwise I'll need to create a function inside the spider file.

Comment: Then why try to use the same spider for everything? You can store theses extract URL in a file or an SQLite file and call another spider from any other .py script